# MVC Core, changed root view folder to UI, erroring with "The default Identity UI layout requires a partial view '_LoginPartial'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I've changed my directory structure for my MVC Core 2.2 site.  I have place the View information in a UI folder off of the root folder.  So my folder structure is as follows:

```
UI +- Areas
   +- Controllers
   +- ViewHelpers
   +- ViewModels
   +- View
      +- Account
       ...
      +- Shared
```

Now, I am getting the following error when I navigate to a view whose controller has an **[Authorize]**.  If I remove the authorize attribute, the error disappears.  The error is as follows:

```
InvalidOperationException: The default Identity UI layout requires a partial view '_LoginPartial' usually located at '/Pages/_LoginPartial' or at '/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial' to work. Based on your configuration we have looked at it in the following locations:
/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Pages/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V4.Pages.Internal.Areas_Identity_Pages__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__42_1()
```

In my ConfigureServices method I have the following,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
    {
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        o.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    });
    services.AddSession();
}
```

It would be great if I could also understand what is happening.

Comment: Are you adding Identity into an existing application? Or just changing the folder structure as you said. It seems you have a namespace issue with _LoginPartial

Comment: Yes, the application has Identity.  It was added by **New Scaffold Item**.  The _LoginPartial current location is \UI\Views\Shared\_LoginPartila.cshtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution to moving the **Identity Scaffolding** code.

I am trying to use **Clear Architecture** in the conversion of a .Net Framework MVC/API/Identity site to a MVC Core 2.2 site.
My inspiration come from the following video:  [Clean Architecture with ASP.NET Core 2.2 - Jason Taylor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zygw4UAxCdg)

My version of the directory structure is as follow:

```
\+- Application 
 |  +- Commands
 +- Domain
 |  +- Entities
 +- Infrastructure
 +- UI
    +- Identity
    |  +- Pages
    |     +- Account
    |      ...
    +- Controllers
    +- ViewHelpers
    +- ViewModels
    +- View
       +- Company
           ...
          +- Shared
```

In my app, I changed the **IdentityUser** and **IdentityRole** classed and the **Scaffolding Identity** directory did not fit the above.
Unfortunately I could not find an example on how to handle the default **Identity** directory.

My solution was to create the **Scaffolding Identity** and convert from an **Area** to a **Page** format.  This is a process with a lot of search and replace, and fraught with problems.

The first step is to create the directory structure.  The next step is to create the **Scaffolding Identity**.  Many how-tos exist, but the  [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) works for me.
You must get this working first, before moving the folder!
To getting **Identity** to work, you will need to search and replace **UserManager<IdentityUser>** and **SignInManager<IdentityUser>**.  Do a final search (only) for **IdentityUser** and manually fix up the DownloadPersonalDataModel page.

Add using statement to the razor pages that reference ApplicationUser:

> using .Domain.Entities;

and to _LoginPartial

> @using .Domain.Entities

Test it.

Drag the Controllers/Views/Models folder under the UI folder.  I renamed Models to ViewModels (optional).  Search and replace the namespaces to the new namespaces.

- .Controllers -> .UI.Controllers
- .Models     -> .UI.ViewModels      (in _ViewImports.cshtml)
- /Views/Shared/           -> /UI/Views/Shared/

Add the Razor View engine options to search the new UI path for view/page/area as follows:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    // {2} is area, {1} is controller,{0} is the action
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    // now razor pages
    o.PageViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    o.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    //
    o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    // now razor areas
    o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    Console.WriteLine(o);
});
```

If you get a 'The following locations were searched:' error message, the Console.WriteLine in the above is a great place to place a break point to see what is available and what is set.

Test the page access.  When everything is clean, then you can drag the **Identity** folder into the **UI* folder.
Search and replace the namespace to the new namespace.
 - .Areas.Identity -> .UI.Identity

Change the _LoginPartial and search and replace Areas (to remove area):
 - asp-area="Identity" -> asp-area=""

Change the MVC Razor options as follows:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.AllowAreas = false;
            options.Conventions.Clear();
            options.RootDirectory = "/UI/Identity/Pages";
            Console.WriteLine(options);
        });
```

Change the Razor View engine options as follows:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    ...
    // now razor areas
    o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Identity/Account/Manage/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    Console.WriteLine(o);
}
```

Now try it... the path to the **Identity** pages is no longer **/Identity/Account**, but it is now **/Account**

Answer (score 3):

From the error ,the project did not find `_LoginPartial` in the location of the error prompt, try the following two methods：

1. directly add `_LoginPartial` under the `UI/Areas/Identity/Pages`,and change `PageViewLocationFormats` with `AreaPageViewLocationFormats` in your Configure

   ```
       services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
       {

           o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
           o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
           o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);

           o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Clear();
           o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
       });
   ```

   [image]
2. Add another AreaPageViewLocationFormat like below :

   ```
       services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
       {

           o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
           o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
           o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);

           o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Clear();
           o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
           o.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add("/UI/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
       });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this has moved me along.  I am still working through the issues.

Comment: @P.Huhn ,  If you find my solution works , could you mark my reply as answer ? This will help others who may have the same question to find the answer quickly. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Xueli, I am trying to use **Clear Architecture** in the conversion of a .Net Framework MVC/API/Identity site. My version has root folders of **Application**, **Domain**, **Infrastructure** and **UI**.  I have used **Scaffolding Item** to add Identity.
I did not know that moving the **Identity** was the problem.  Per various people in Core 2.1, Area is hard code and cannot be changed.  The UI\Area\Identity stops working and reverts to the DLL version of **Identity**. Your solution is most likely not going to work; but, I am pursuing converting the **Identity Area** into a **Page**.