# how to move Areas folder to subfolder in DotNet Core with mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identity, area, asp.net-core-5.0

I moved 'Areas' folder to this 'ControlPanel'.
When I run project, get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The default Identity UI layout requires a partial view '_LoginPartial' usually located at '/Pages/_LoginPartial' or at '/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial' to work. Based on your configuration we have looked at it in the following locations:
/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Pages/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V4.Pages.Internal.Areas_Identity_Pages__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__42_1().
```

could you please help me to move my Areas folder to subfolder named 'ControlPanel'?

Comment: Just change "Areas" in the pathes to "ControlPane"l in the affected views

Comment: See at the bottom of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58368346/3258851